# want different maven project structure

Tags: maven

Trying to understand maven flow.Need to create a folder called '**my-source**' and copy multiple files in the same folder.

And  i want a maven build zip file which should contain 'my-source' folder and its contents.How do i do that?Where ever articles i refer  am seeing only java project/folder structure examples.

Also i have seen sourcedirectory/outputdirectory. Not sure where i can modify these values as i couldnot find location of effectivepom

So please give me the process to fulfil my requirement

Comment: If you trying to understand Maven the first and most important thing is to understand the basic concept. Convention over Configuration which means follow the defaults and don't try to change them only if you have a really really good reason where I have my doubts about. Can you show the folder structure of your project ?

Comment: yes i agree , maven follows convention over configuration. But just wanted to know if maven can build a non java project where folder structure is different from Java
(Unable to add project structure image here)

Comment: project structure is simple. there will be folder "projectA" and it will have "mysource" folder  and also pom.xml

Note: mysource folder will have multiple files (like sql,html...etc..). After build finishes i should receive target folder in projectA which should contain a zip of all files

Comment: Create the structure `src/main/scripts` put an assembly descriptor into your project `src/assemblies/` and describe how the zip file should look like (see the docs for maven-assembly-plugin)...add the maven-assembly-plugin to the pom and that's it..?

Comment: @rajesh If you do not want to build a java project, are you sure you need a build tool? Your question appears to be only about zipping files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a zip file with all your contents you will have to use the maven assembly plugin in your pom.xml. Apart from this, you will need one more file (say bin.xml) that will tell which all files you want to be packaged in the zip. The assembly plugin in the pom.xml will simply point to the bin.xml file.
See a sample code for pom.xml below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin> <!-- Create a zip file with the contents you want deployed -->
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>    // very important. This is where we will tell where our bin.xml is located
                    </descriptors>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Now create a folder structure like src/assembly and add a file with the name bin.xml.  See below for a sample code that should go inside bin.xml.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>distrib</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>  
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/my-source</directory>    // the folder that you want to the packaged in the zip file
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>    // the location within the zip file where your folder should be copied. In this case it will place the my-source directory at the root level of the zip file.
            <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```